# asp:UpdatePanel + postback + JQuery class selector

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I have simple page with asp:UpdatePanel and button that performs postback. Page has simple script that is in Page_Load server method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "initPage", "initPage();", true);
```

Javascript function initPage() looks like this:

```
function initPage(){
  $('.textBoxClass').each(function (index) {
    alert(index);
  }
}
```

Problem is, that after clicking postback button, length of $('.textBoxClass') increases by one. There is no code-generation, DOM manipulation or class adding. I thing it has something to do with UpdatePanel (?), but is there any way to get rid of class count increasing?

Comment: Maybe there is error between keyboard and chair - I have try again this simple example and everything is OK now. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

at the updatepanel properties and update the panel only if necessary with the method Update().

You can also try to comment the updatepanel to make some tests with the alert message

Tell us if that behaviour remains.